# Remember the slider position and lazy load - bxslider

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bxslider

I am using [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) in my website, and it works great. 
However, I have 1 question:

My slider has total about 15 images, and 2 are shown at any point on the screen. Is there any way to have an arrangement such as when the user loads the page, only 2 are downloaded and when she clicks on next, only then the next 2 are downloaded, so that the page load does not take for ever?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this same issue and ended up with the following solution:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="slider">
    ...
    <li class="slide">
        <img src="[PLACEHOLDER IMAGE]" data-src="[ACTUAL IMAGE]">
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function loadSlide( slider, $element ) {
    var page = slider.getCurrentSlide(),
        visible = Math.floor( $element.closest( '.bx-viewport' ).width() / $element.find( '.slide' ).width() ),
        slides = $element.find( '.slide:not(.bx-clone)' ),
        firstSlide = slides.eq( page * visible );

    for ( var i = 0; i < visible; i++ ) {
        var img = firstSlide.find( 'img' ),
            imgSrc = img.attr( 'data-src' );

        if ( imgSrc && imgSrc !== '' ) {
            img.hide().attr( 'src', imgSrc ).fadeIn().removeAttr( 'data-src' );
        }

        firstSlide = firstSlide.next( '.slide' );
    }
}

// init bxSlider
$( '.slider' ).each( function( idx, el ) {
    var $el = $( el ),
        thisSlider = $el.bxSlider({
             // config options
             onSlideBefore: function() {
                 loadSlide( thisSlider, $el );
             }
    });
});
```

**Some notes:**

1. I initialized the script using `$.each` instead of just `$('.slider').bxSlider()` because bxSlider wasn't passing a reference to the slider instance, and I needed that to use the `getCurrentSlide` method.
2. `getCurrentSlide` lets us know which page we're moving to, so we can use that to figure out which element is first on that page. I was having trouble getting that info strictly from bxSlider, but it's probably easier than I'm making it.
3. As it's moving through images on the slide, it bails if they don't have a `data-src` attribute. If it does, it replaces the `src` attribute with it, and fades the image in.
4. Make sure your first page of images reference valid images since this is only set up to handle when the slider changes pages.
5. I'm 90% sure my solution is needlessly complicated, but it works for me.

You can check a working example here: http://codepen.io/a_double/pen/RNaRZw

Hope that helps!